# Add to $PATH in linux so that it's available to daemons

Tags: linux, environment-variables, daemon

Where can I add to a $PATH so that it's available to all daemons?  So that it's "included" or "sourced" before daemons start?

Many thanks!

Comment: Not an XPATH question, removed the tag.

Comment: hm.  didn't mean to put that there..  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misread that, if you want to run something before daemons you could create a cron job or...

> The system startup files are located in /etc/rc2.d. You can add a file to this directory with the commands you want to run at system startup. Suppose you want to delete some temp files at system startup, you could put a file named TempFileDel in your /etc/rc2.d with the commands to delete your temporary files, so it'll run every time system reboots.
>
> Helo. 
> As shereenmotor says, usually, startup scripts are located in /etc/rc2.d, but this depends on the UNIX/Linux you run and your system's default run level.
> But I'm afraid it's not that easy. The script name must follow some rules:
> - There are two kind of scripts, let's say: kill scripts and start scripts. Both stored in /etc/rcX.d.
> - kill scripts are executed first, after that start scripts.
> - kill scripts name must start with a "K".
> - start sctipts name must start with a "S".
> - Following the first letter, there must be a two digit number. This lets "rc" know the order for the execution of the sctrips. rc is the "master" script which calls the others. Have a look at your /etc/inittab.
> - Finally, a name of your choice.
>
> when "rc" calls this scripts it adds a parameter: start for "S" scripts and stop for "K" scripts. This allows you to use the same script for both operations, just using links.

create a file 
`#!/bin/ksh
case $1 in
start)
   echo Removing file...
   rm /tmp/somefile;;
stop)
   echo bye!;;
esac`

and then

`ln -s /path/to/TempFileDel /etc/rc2.d/S10TempFileDel
ln -s /path/to/TempFileDel /etc/rc2.d/K10TempFileDel`

Comment: This is probably perfect.  I'll give it a shot!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score 0):

Daemons are started many different ways on different varieties of UNIX.  Most of them have a way to setup the environment.

Perhaps the most fundamental is to set the environment for the init process, often through /etc/inittab.  This will set the starting environment for all processes in the system.

Comment: Sounds great.  Though, I'm in Ubuntu, and I don't see that file

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script or a command, you could put it in /bin/ and set the appropiate owner and permisions using chmod and chown